# Why would import.sql fail in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, h2

I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUb52gHQGLE) on Spring Boot.

The guy goes fairly quickly but it seems like everything is the same with our code. When I get to the point to view the H2 console I noticed I'm missing my `Speaker` table.

I've seen lots of questions on here, blogs everywhere, and it seems *all you have to do is have the file in `main/resources`* and it works. Well, it doesn't!

Some of the answers talk about `persistence.xml` and/or a configuration file for H2. Well, I don't have those and neither does that tutorial and yet his works.

I'm finding that some of the most seemingly simple things are terribly frustrating with Spring and I'm sick of looking around and finding the same answer which doesn't work.

Can someone shed some light on why this would fail?

I can't imagine what else I would need aside from my `pom.xml` since the tutorial simply adds `import.sql` and like everyone else claims - it just works.
I will add more if needed.

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

import.sql

```sql
INSERT INTO SPEAKER(ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TWITTER, BIO) VALUES (0, 'Foo', 'Baz', 'foobaz', 'Foo Baz hates Twitter');
INSERT INTO SPEAKER(ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TWITTER, BIO) VALUES (1, 'Bar', 'Baz', 'barbaz', 'Bar Baz hates Twitter too');
INSERT INTO SPEAKER(ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TWITTER, BIO) VALUES (2, 'Santa', 'Clause', 'saintnick', 'Santa is a Twitter champ');
```

Comment: `import.sql` isn't (or shouldn't) be used to create tables, that is what the `schema.sql` is for. So what is in the `import.sql`. Generally schema creation is done with a `schema.sql` or left to the JPA provider.

Comment: @M.Deinum, that's interesting. That's exactly what the guy does. I'll rename it and see as well as ad it's contents here. It's also the same as far as statements...

Comment: Next to that H2 (as I saw in the tutorial) is at first used as an in memory database to which you cannot connect. So if you are trying to use the console to connect to the in memory database it won't work as you will see a new database instead of the one used by the tutorial. At least for the external console, if you are using the servlet registered in the tutorial it should work (as that should reuse the existing datasource).

Comment: @M.Deinum, I guess that's it. I'm confused by that though. Maybe because they don't make that clear. So, does that mean it is being imported but I just can't see it from the console?

Comment: Which console are you using? Are you running a stand alone console or the one they include as servlet in the tutorial?

Comment: Everything I'm doing is just like the tut. So it's the WebServlet. @M.Deinum

Comment: @Ahmed Ashour - nice edit. Learned something new I probably should've known :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in a minor but important detail with a little more careful investigation. Apparently, when the console started it added default values to the form entries and one differed from the tutorial's.

For the `JDBC URL` the default was `jdbc:h2:~/test`.

[image]

I had to change it to `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`.

[image]

I'm now able to see the `Speaker` table and data.

Once I made the change it stayed as the default. I suppose the author had already done that and I missed the difference.

Thanks for your help @M. Deinum!

Comment: you can change the name of the datasource via `spring.datasource.name`; its default value is `testdb` indeed.